# Shrink list view when less items are present

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a widget that displays two list view (one under the groups header, the other under the alerts header) with a minimum and maximum height.

I've managed to get maximum heights working via a `ConstrainedBox` wrapping everything however I've been unable to get a mimnimum height working. Idearly I would like the lists to like everything to shink if there are fewer items in both lists.

For example, in the screenshot below there are only two items in one list and none in the other so I would like the overall widget to shrink down to roughly half its current size

[image]

From what I can see in the Widget Inspector, the list itself is not taking up any more space than it needs however the Column appears to be taking up all the space the parent constraint is allowing for. I've tried messing with `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,` howeve this doesn't appear to have had any effect.

How can I prevent this column from taking all the extra space?

[image]

```dart
return ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 300, minHeight: 50),
  child: Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: [
      Flexible(
        flex: 1,
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: Text("Groups")),
              const Divider(),
              ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 2,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                        ...
                      ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        flex: 1,
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: Text("Alerts")),
              const Divider(),
              ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 2,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                        ...
                      ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Edit after suggestions:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

- Remove `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` from the row
- Add `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to the columns

*Edit (in response to the comment):*

To make the lists same size. Not sure if there is a straightforward way.

One hacky way I can think of is by setting the `itemCount` of both lists equal to the length of the list with most items. And in `itemBuilder`, return an empty ListTile when the index is out of available items to show. Example -

```
import 'dart:math';

const groupsCount = 2;
const alertsCount = 4;
final biggestCount = max(groupsCount, alertsCount);

Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Card(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: Text("Groups")),
            const Divider(),
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: biggestCount,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                if (index < groupsCount) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text('Group $index'));
                } else {
                  return const ListTile();
                }
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Card(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: Text("Alerts")),
            const Divider(),
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: biggestCount,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                if (index < alertsCount) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text('Alert $index'));
                } else {
                  return const ListTile();
                }
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

[image]

Comment: That appears to have done the trick, thankyou very much. The one downside is if there are less items in one of the list than the other, the sizes of the outside boxes dont line up (see bottom screenshot for an example). Any idea how I could make both boxes fill all available space within the parent without expanding beyond the height of the largest list? I.e. In the screenshot at the bottom, how can I make the groups box match the size of the alerts box? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Not sure how to make them the same size. But if it is good enough, you can set `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` for the Row, so they are aligned at the top atleast.